# Need help in understanding getAcceptedIssuers method

Tags: java, android, x509certificate

I am writing a code to get all the trusted certificates from android device.

Here's my code,

```
public class MyX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
X509TrustManager pkixTrustManager;

public MyX509TrustManager(KeyStore keystore)
        throws Exception {

    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
    tmf.init(keystore);

    TrustManager tms[] = tmf.getTrustManagers();

    for (int i = 0; i < tms.length; i++) {
        if (tms[i] instanceof X509TrustManager) {
            pkixTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) tms[i];

            System.out.println("The class is " + pkixTrustManager.getClass());
            return;
        }
    }

    throw new Exception("Couldn't initialize");
}

public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
        throws CertificateException {

    try {
        pkixTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(arg0, arg1);
    } catch (CertificateException excep) {

    }

}

public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
        throws CertificateException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        pkixTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(arg0, arg1);
    } catch (CertificateException excep) {

    }
}

public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {


    System.out.println("Control inside the issuers method");

    System.out.println( "Number of trusted certificates is "+   pkixTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers().length);
    return pkixTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();

}
}
```

When I call getAcceptedIssuers method I am getting the empty array(Confirmed by the array length returned by getacceptedIssuers methos)

What I am doing wrong here.

Can any one help me on this please to get the list of trusted certificates from android device.

**EDIT**

I am calling the constructor of MyX509TrustManager in another class:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
// KeyStore.getDefaultType() returns "BKS"

MyX509TrustManager mm = new MyX509TrustManager(ks);

X509Certificate [] trucerts = m.getAcceptedIssuers();
```

How can I load the keystore with trusted certificates?

Comment: It means you have no trusted certificates in your KeyStore. Do you have some reason to believe otherwise? Evidence?

Comment: It appears that you're creating a KeyStore object but never loading it. So it's empty. So it has no accepted issuers in it. If you remove all this code and just use a default SSLContext, you should be using whatever trusted issuers are provided with the platform.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I achieve this by using sslcontext. I searched in the internet but didn't get clear idea.   Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Err, SSLContext.getDefault()? You didn't find that anywhere

Answer (score 1):

The keystore you provided when calling the constructor `MyX509TrustManager(KeyStore keystore)` didn't hold any certificate for any Certification Authority.

For example, you can create a KeyStore object and fill it with the contents (key, certificate, CA certificates,...) of a keystore in your filesystem:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

// get user password and file input stream
char[] password = "password of the keystore in the file system";

java.io.FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
    fis = new java.io.FileInputStream("keyStoreName");
    ks.load(fis, password);
} finally {
    if (fis != null) {
        fis.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I am calling the constructor of MyX509TrustManager in another class like,

KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
 // KeyStore.getDefaultType() returns "BKS"

MyX509TrustManager mm = new MyX509TrustManager(ks); 

X509Certificate [] trucerts = m.getAcceptedIssuers();

Here,How can I load the keystore with trusted certificates.

Appreciate your help...

Comment: You are loading an empty keystore into MyX509TrustManager. So, it is not strange that MyX509TrustManager doesn't find any trust manager in the keystore. I wrote you an example showing how to load an existing keystore. So, you only have to user `keytool` to create a keystore matching your needs.

Comment: I am able to get the trusted certificates in an android mobile by using,

X509certificate [] trustCertificate = new X509Certificate [0];

TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
                    .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init((KeyStore) null);
X509TrustManager xtm = (X509TrustManager) tmf.getTrustManagers()[0];

   for(int i=0; i<xtm.getAcceptedIssuers().length; i++){

this.trustCertificate = xtm.getAcceptedIssuers();

}

But however this xtm.getAcceptedIssuers is taking more time to process.

Any idea on this will be really helpful.